# How to a file uploading using Automator in apple script?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automator

I’m new to automator. This is what I’m trying to achieve.

I have the code for uploading the file in Safari using applescript ( which will upload the file `myFile` points to):

```
on run argv
    set myFile to item 1 of argv
    activate application "Safari"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
        delay 2
        key code 51
        delay 2
        keystroke myFile
        delay 30
        key code 52
        delay 10
        key code 52
        delay 5
    end tell
end run
```

This applescript is been called by Java and it works fine.

This is working totally fine. But I want to put this in automator service, so that Safari has directly access to the applescripts, rather than Java doing it. Now I have two questions:

1. Many Safari will be running and calling this service. So which safari needs to give the file uploading process needs to be figured out. Is it possible for the automator to find the process id of the application which called it ?
2. If so, then how shall I pass the parameter (the file location to be uploaded) to the automator, when the service is called?

Thanks in advance.